# Trigonometric Functions in Pseudo Code

Tags: trigonometry, pseudocode

I'm searching for Trigonometric Functions in Pseudo Code.
I'm Not good at mathematics, so I can't do much with the formulas in the Wikipedia.
Mainly I'm searching for Sine, Cosine, Tangent and the inverse functions (sin⁻¹, cos⁻¹, tan⁻¹) of them.
There are also other Trigonometric Functions. But for me the above are the most important.

If it is possible, I would be happy if in the pseudo code only variables, `for`, `if`, and operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `sqrt()`) are used, because I do not have a library with advanced mathematics functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigonometry functions are [Transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function).
You cannot find an **exact** expression of them in term of polynomial algebra.

You can **approximate** them though.

The usual approach is to use periodicity and symmetry to reduce an angle α into and equivalent angle α′ such that *sin*(α) = *sin*(α′) but α′ ≪ α.
Simply put you reduce any angle into and angle in the first quadrant or similar, this is easier than it looks.
Once you have a small angle, you can use [Taylor Series Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) to compute the function up to a fixed error magnitude.

[Here](http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/algorithms.htm#sin) is a tutorial page.

---

Another approach is to use a [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table#Computing_sines).
This is especially useful when you can keep track of the required precision of the process and is very fast.
However it takes more memory and may give rise to a step-looking function.
[Here](https://jfdube.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/trigonometric-look-up-tables-revisited/) an introductory page.

---

Another approach is to use [CORDIC Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC), this is specially suited for hardware that lacks multiplication support (like some MIPS and ARM chips).
From Wikipedia:

> CORDIC is generally faster than other approaches when a hardware multiplier is not available (e.g., a microcontroller) [...]
>
> On the other hand, when a hardware multiplier is available (e.g., in a DSP microprocessor), table-lookup methods and power series are generally faster than CORDIC.